# How to pull up Chrome Console in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have 2 questions about the same thing please ;)

I am developing an extension for Code and I need to see the Chrime console. Therefore:

1. How can I pull up Chrome Console to see the Console messages coming from my extension
2. How can I pull up a Chrome Console for the HTML content that I and displaying in my extension via DocumentProvider?

The question 2 is there as I happened to visualize the Console after some exception but I could not access the HTML and JS content of the extension generated page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `Help -> Toggle Developer Tools`.

Comment: For the web console you need to map it to viewing console of WebView

Comment: This was also binded to `cmd/ctrl + i` for me if anyone wants the shortcut. The shortcut didn't end up working for me though.